# Vehicle routing problem with drops and pickups with capacity constraints

Tags: constraint-programming, or-tools, vehicle-routing

I am using Google OR Tools for the problem:

Vehicles always start from the depot with all the weights loaded for drop points. And there are pickup points from where they have to load weights. The tour has to be completed within a time window of 10 hours.

Example:

> Nodes = [A,  B,  C,  D,  E,  F,  G]
>
> Weights = [50, 60, 30, 20, 80, 90, 40]
>
> PointType = [D,  D,  P,  D,  P,  D,  D] where D = Delivery and P = Pickup

I have tried using the [Pickup Deliveries](https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/pickup_delivery) example in OR Tools and used dummy pickup node for every drop and dummy drop node for every pickup.
Thus, having a unique pickup and drop combination.

This approach works well for upto 50-60 locations but the solver fails to return any solution for large number of locations (135 locations and hence 135 * 2 = 270 nodes, because one dummy node for each).

Is there another way to solve this problem using OR tools, that does not require using dummy nodes, which would effectively lower the total nodes?

Comment: Can you try playing around with the algorithms? I have noticed that OR-tools will not return a solution if the first solution algorithm fails to generate an initial solution. Your best bet is to try various algorithms to see what works best for your use case. Also, try to make nodes optional, that significantly improves the solver speed.

Answer (score 0):

OR-tools was not generating a solution because the problem of 135 nodes was infeasible within the Time Windows that I was passing.

It has no trouble generating solution when time window is right.

Also, creating dummy/duplicate nodes is probably necessary, because in any variant of Travelling Salesman Problem (TSP), one node can only be visited once.